# Arrangements and Grouping

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Find the number of ways in which a team of 3 men and 2
women can be selected from a group of 6 men and 5 women?

Would the answer just be 6C3 x 5C2 ?

Comment: Yes, it would.  $\quad$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: hdhfs Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

For each of the $\binom{6}{3}$ three of the six men can be selected, it is possible to select two of the five women in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways.  Hence, the number of admissible selections is indeed $\binom{6}{3}\binom{5}{2}$.